# Enviar datos de input a textarea (o algún otro elemento donde pueda mandar los datos)

Tags: javascript, input, textarea

Excelente día a todos. Necesito mandar la información almacenada en una variable a un textarea de JS. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? de antemano, gracias

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: La pregunta ya tiene solucion,  pero te recomiendo pasar por el [tour] siendo un usuario nuevo y tambien de paso leer [ask], par poder que puedas hacer preguntas mejor recibidas y validas por la comunidad, lo ideal en cualquier pregunta y lo que casi nunca puede faltar es el codigo detras el cual esta la pregunta,  en tu caso no haz puesto ningun codigo,  por eso el voto negativo,  tambien recordar que la comunidad no responde preguntas basadas en opiniones (estan prohibidas), en tu caso no se trata de una pregunta basada en opiniones,  pero te lo comento.

Answer (score 2):

Debes asignar el valor de tu variable al valor del textarea:

```
document.getElementById("el id de tu text area").value = tuVariable;
```

Comment: muchas gracias! probaré

Comment: Me funcionó! muchas gracias!

Comment: Normalmente no se responden a preguntas que no contienen un codigo detras [answer], pero considero que esta respuesta aunque es muy simple es util, por esta razon te di un +1, pero esta es la excepcion y no la regla, considera tener en cuenta a que tipo de preguntas debes responder,  para que los usuarios mas experimentados no voten negativamente tu respuesta, esto ocurre muy a menudo,  por que los usuarios nuevos no tienen en cuenta esta pagina [answer] ni tampoco esta [ask].

Comment: Tomo nota. Leeré atentamente la página [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).